# Why are points on the axis of a circuit with axial symmetry equipotential?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, symmetry, electrical-resistance, voltage

Given the following electrical circuit:

[image]

How to explain that L and K are equipotential?

More generic question: why given any electrical circuit with axial symmetry, points that belong to the axis are equipotential:

[image]

**P.S.** It's derived from my more complex homework, but I am trying to understand how things work, not just trying to get it solved.

**Update.** There is a resistance between K and L instead of ideal wire.

Comment: They're joined by an ideal wire, with no resistance; therefore, they're required to be at the same potential, because there can be no voltage drop on an ideal wire.

Comment: @probably_someone Ok, but if left 5R would become 3R, then I believe L and R hadn't been equipotential anymore...

Comment: Does changing 5R to 3R change anything that I said? Does it change the fact that there can be no voltage drop on an ideal wire?

Comment: @probably_someone Updated the question.

Comment: The updated answer below is correct.

Comment: @probably_someone It is. Still if there is somewhat more physics-based (not analytical) explanation it would be nice to listen to it.

Comment: In the triangular example, current can flow from A to B while passing through the KL wire in exactly two ways: A->K->L->B and A->L->K->B. The resistance encountered along these two paths is identical, but the two paths have opposite directions of current flow through KL. Equal currents in opposite directions exactly cancel, leaving no current in KL.

Comment: The square example is a bit more complicated, but the underlying principle is the same: if you were to add up the current produced in the middle wires in each possible path from A to B, you'd find that the currents in the middle wires exactly cancel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the wire is ideal and since there are no resistances between the point L and K, the potential drop between L and K is zero i.e potential does not change. So the potential is same anywhere in between those two points and therefore, they are equipotential.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Mathematical Proof: Assume potential at A, L, K and B are A, x, y and B. Using Kirchhoff's law we get:
$$\frac{y-B}{R}+\frac{y-x}{4R}+\frac{y-0}{R}=0$$
$$\frac{x-0}{2R}+\frac{x-y}{4R}+\frac{x-B}{2R}=0$$
Upon addition of the above equations and further simplification, we get $x=\frac{B}{2}$ and $y=\frac{B}{2}$. This means the potential at L and K are same i.e equipotential and the existence of the 4R resistor does not matter.

However, it is very difficult to use Kirchhoff's law every time, especially when you have something as ambiguous as a circuit like this:

[image]

For these type of circuits, we must find symmetricity. However, note that if there is no symmetricity then Kirchhoff's law is the only way to solve this. Luckily there is symmetricity here and I can guide you through the thought process. Let us take the first diagram as an example:

[image]

Let us say $i$ current flows in through A which breaks as $i_1$ in wire AK and $i_2$ in wire AL. Now since the wires connected to B have similar resistances as the wires connected to A, the same amount of current must flow in wire LB as in AL and exit through B and the same amount of current must flow in the wire KB as in AK and exit through B. So now we can notice that the $i_1$ current in AK does not enter the wire LK and the $i_2$ current in AL does not enter the wire LK. This means, there is no flow of charge or current through the wire LK.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Nice proof, thanks. Is there somewhat more physics-based explanation, which could be generalized to the arbitrary circuit having axial symmetry?

Comment: Just added a few more details. I hope it was helpful. @DenisKulagin